# HTML select text within tags in VB6

Tags: html, vb6

I need to select text inside HTML tags, but the options I tested are giving error.
When I run the code run-time error 13 occurs

This is the HTML example to filter: [dotnetfiddle.net/mk7l1x](http://dotnetfiddle.net/mk7l1x)

Here's the code:

```
Dim start As Long
Dim end As Long
Dim meutext As Long

Txt_nosite.Text = Replace (Txt_nosite.Text, "" "", "Chr (34)")

start = InStr (Txt_nosite.Text, "<p class = Chr (34) p-author timeChr 
(34)> 06/22/2019 08:16 </ p>")
end = InStr (Txt_nosite.Text, "<p class = Chr (34) thumb-description Chr 
(34)>"
meutext = Mid (Txt_nosite.Text, start, end - start)
Txt_nosite.Text = meutext
```

Comment: This is the HTML example to filter: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mk7l1x

Comment: At which point in the code does the error come from?

Comment: Do you actually have CHR() function calls inside a string literal? That will just be treated as part of the string...

Comment: Actually, this code will not compile as-is.  The `"" ""` inside the `Replace` function will display a compile error.

Comment: Change the:
Dim start As string
Dim end As string
Dim meutext As String

and resolve it!

Answer (score 0):

The immediate source of the error 13 (Type mismatch) would be that you're assigning the results of the `Mid` call to the long variable `meutext`. The `Mid` function returns a string and in this example that string is not convertible to a numeric quantity.

Changing `meutext` to a string will probably resolve that problem:

```
Dim start As Long
Dim end As Long
Dim meutext As String

Txt_nosite.Text = Replace (Txt_nosite.Text, "" "", "Chr (34)")

start = InStr (Txt_nosite.Text, "<p class = Chr (34) p-author timeChr (34)> 06/22/2019 08:16 </ p>")
end = InStr (Txt_nosite.Text, "<p class = Chr (34) thumb-description Chr (34)>"
meutext = Mid (Txt_nosite.Text, start, end - start)
Txt_nosite.Text = meutext
```

But once you resolve that error, this code will probably not produce the results you desire.  As DaveInCaz implies, having an apparent Chr function call inside the string constants is not going to insert a quotation mark in your string (`Chr(34)` is a `"`).